# How can I sort a list of objects by a member of each object?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

```
class candle
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public double open { get; set; }
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double close { get; set; }     
}
List<candle> candleList = new List<candle>();
```

Assuming I have added many candles to candeList, How can I then sort candleList by date?

Also, how can I remove all duplicate entries from candleList?

Thank you

Comment: `candleList.OrderBy(x=>x.date)` :)

Comment: Two pertinent questions: 1) do you want to sort the list itself or iterate a sorted output? 2) How do you consider two `candle` instances equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty standard, simple linq.

```
var candleList = candleList.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.date).ToList();
```

As Adam mentioned below, this will only remove duplicate instances within the list, not instances which all of the same property values.

You can implement your own `IEqualityComparer<Candle>` as an option to get passed this.  [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

You may want to take a look at msdn, and read up on Linq and Enumerable Methods:
[MSDN - Enumerable Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx)

Comment: `Distinct` on a class would just do reference equality, not anything with the property values. Also, that sort is not in-place, it produces an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, your point is extremely valid and relevant.  But it does not make my answer incorrect (that's to the downvoter).  I have provided more information.

Comment: I noticed, and I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I then sort candleList by date?*

```
var orderedList = candleList.OrderBy(p=>p.date);
```

> *Also, how can I remove all duplicate entries from candleList?*

You should tell us how you compare two `candle` objects. Assuming by `date` you can do:

```
var uniqueList = candleList.GroupBy(p=>p.date).Where(p=>p.Count() == 1).ToList();
```

Also, you can use `Distinct()` or intorduce a `IEqualityComparer<candle>` to this method to compare two candle objects and remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using .NET 3.5 and above, you can use the OrderBy extension over IList like so:

```
var orderList = candleList.OrderBy(s => s.date);
```

Alternative you can use the SortBy

```
var orderList = candleList.SortBy((x, y) => x.date.CompareTo(y.date) );
```

To remove the duplicates you can do:

```
var distinctList = orderList.GroupBy(x => x.date).Select(grp => grp.First());
```

Finally to get the list again do

```
var finalList = distinctList.ToList();
```

In fluent way:

```
List<candle> finalList = candleList.OrderBy(s => s.date).Distinct().ToList();
```

By the way there quite a few other questions in stackoverflow that explains each of this questions, search them and you'll find other details.